# Spark CSV read option for number format

Tags: apache-spark

I'm loading a CSV file with numbers:

```
spark.read.format("csv")
  .schema(StructType(Seq(StructField("result", IntegerType, true))))
  .option("mode", "FAILFAST")
  .option("delimiter", "|")
  .option("encoding", "utf8")
  .load(file)

Caused by: FileReadException: Error while reading file blah.csv.
Caused by: Malformed records are detected in record parsing. Parse Mode: FAILFAST. To process malformed records as null result, try setting the option 'mode' as 'PERMISSIVE'.
Caused by: BadRecordException: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "65,9"
Caused by: NumberFormatException: For input string: "65,9"
```

Oops... we use comma as decimal point. I see data source options like `dateFormat` and `timestampFormat`, but not anything about number format (decimal point and/or grouping).

Can I somehow specify force Spark to handle commas? Or is the only way loading it as string and parse manually?

Comment: Whats stopping you to read it as a `StringType` & clean it [remove `,`] then convert it back to `FloatType`

Comment: What's stopping me to read it as `StringType`, translate `,` to `.`, cast to `IntegerType`, since `cast` silently returns `null` for non-numbers and I want `FAILFAST` also scan the resulting dataframe and throw exception if any `null` is found, except when the raw field was `null` as well; do this for a dozen of fields? Nothing, I will do exactly this if there's no other way :) I just hoped for a leaner solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should read data in String format then remove comma and convert it to float.

Spark provides various options while reading but doesn't allow to customize any options. Like in your case you will need to do it manually only.

Also I think any leaner solution(if any) will also follow same steps in backend.